# Responsive form, how can I maintain a div next to the other while responsive

Tags: html, css, forms

[image: trying to get the red "X" to the right of the input]

```
    <div class="formRow" style="">
                <div class="labeldiv">
                <label class="desc" id="title1" for="full_name" style="">How much cover would you like?<br>(Between £20,000 and £3,000,000.)</label>
                </div>
                <div class="answerSet" style="">
                     <div class="answer"><input type="text"  class="mediumInput ">" ></div> 

                     <div class="validation-icon"></div>
                     <div class="message-container">
                        <div class="validation-message">This is a required field.</div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="help-messages"></div>
                </div>
            </div>




@media (min-width: 600px){
 div.answerSet{
width: 53%;
float: right;
}
div.labeldiv{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width: 47%;
}

#lifeInsuranceFormHolder div.answer {
    padding-top: 20px;
width: auto;
float:left;

}

#lifeInsuranceFormHolder div.answer p {
clear: both;
font-size: 12px;
height: 55px;
text-align: center;
width: 64px;
}

}
```

Hi all,

As seen in the picture, When the window size is smaller, the cross (background picture in "div class='validation'") falls down a line instead of being kept at the side of the input.

How can I keep the div.answer and div.validation as an inline block?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set the container to stop wrapping text, like this:

```
.answerSet {white-space: nowrap;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jezen, I tried it, also giving div.answer and div.validation a display:inline. But it still comes down when making the window smaller. Any thoughts? Thanks.